# How do I diagnose the cause of a Xamarin Android Weak Reference Table Overflow?

Tags: android, memory, xamarin, java-native-interface

I have reports from several users that my app is crashing after about 5 minutes of intensive use. I have received crash logs on Google Play and an example is attached below. The message seems to be:

**JNI ERROR (app bug): weak global reference table overflow (max=51200)'**

I'm not familiar with the JNI and would appreciate so any advice/explanations/suggestions on how to figure this out. The likely cause is something in my code is not getting cleaned up, but what?

The devices that this issue has been reported on are **Nexus 5.x**, **Galaxy S7** and **Nexus 6**.

The relevant code can be found in my open source project: https://gitlab.com/hodgskin-callan/Invention.  However, I don't have the minimum code to reproduce the issue and it does not reproduce on my Nexus 9.  I suspect this issue is not affecting the majority of the Android users.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/bullhead/bullhead:7.1.1/N4F26T/3687331:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'rev_1.0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 10404, tid: 10404, name: .x10host.pathos  >>> com.x10host.pathos <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132] JNI ERROR (app bug): weak global reference table overflow (max=51200)'
    r0 00000000  r1 000028a4  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
    r4 f300558c  r5 00000006  r6 f3005534  r7 0000010c
    r8 00000000  r9 0000000a  sl 00001785  fp f0385400
    ip 0000000b  sp ffde7b50  lr f1a065e7  pc f1a08e44  cpsr 200f0010

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00049e44  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 000475e3  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
    #02 pc 0001d8a5  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 000193f1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
    #04 pc 00017034  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 0031a5f1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+328)
    #06 pc 000b5205  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+1132)
    #07 pc 001bc42b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art22IndirectReferenceTable3AddEjPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+194)
    #08 pc 0023a097  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt16AddWeakGlobalRefEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+46)
    #09 pc 0027f483  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI16NewWeakGlobalRefEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+418)
    #10 pc 0000de14  /data/app/com.x10host.pathos-2/lib/arm/libmonodroid.soapp/com.x10host.pathos-2/lib/arm/libmonodroid.so
```

Comment: There's a whole piece of documentation on gref logging which you can enable to track this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Global_Reference_Messages

Comment: Thanks, I have read this article and enabled the logging.  It says gwrefc 0, almost the entire time.  I was hoping to see it growing over time.  Do you know if there is a way to query the current state of grefc and gwrefc at runtime?  I could give a custom APK to my users for testing.

Comment: You can set an environment property: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/environment/#Xamarin.Android_System_Properties then ask a user for an `adb logcat` as the app crashes? It's gonna be a bit tough if you can't replicate locally.

Comment: Yeah, I can't reproduce and will be tough to get my users to operate adb. Seems like something I should be able to query from the JNI, but I haven't had any luck finding an API.

Answer (score 1):

There's a long, but very useful piece of documentation on this subject here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Global_Reference_Messages

For a first pass through, you should attempt to enable the system property through a `.txt` file that has it's `Build Action` set to `$(AndroidEnvironment)`:

i.e. `debug.mono.log gref`

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/environment/#Xamarin.Android_System_Properties

You would then obtain an `adb logcat` from the device which will include this logging.

However if that doesn't work to your favor:

You should be able to query directly via:

`Java.Interop.JniRuntime.CurrentRuntime.GlobalReferenceCount`

`Java.Interop.JniRuntime.CurrentRuntime.WeakGlobalReferenceCount`

The local references are also tracked in `Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.LocalReferenceCount` which is a thread-local value.

Comment: I did not see that Querying Programmatically section when I read that article!  Although, I think WeakGlobalReferenceCount always return -1 on Xamarin Android.  Line 81 in this file: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/master/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/AndroidRuntime.cs.  I looked it up because I was getting -1 on my Nexus 9.

Comment: That's because I added that section. I do think the -1 thing might be an issue. You should be able to use the `LocalReferenceCount` however https://github.com/xamarin/java.interop/blob/a1d3ecc8ba6e67b96ae1c633194b0e78c2ac5c23/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.cs#L35-L37

Comment: Alright, I have nothing conclusive but I do have some new feedback from one user.  He has observed that when the grefc goes over ~46,000 the app crashes.  When I reproduce the situation on my Nexus 9, the app does not crash and the grefc resets to ~6,000.  Could there be problematic code related to grefc cleanup?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but without a reliable reproduction there's not really much we can do. I would highly advise teaching a user to get an adb log or for you to use more device types in attempt to reproduce. You should add a crash reporting system and log those gref and wref counts periodically.

Comment: A crash reporting system was good advice so I integrated with HockeyApp.  Turns out that this type of crash is not tracked and that I need to ask the Xamarin team for help - https://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/74432-are-there-types-of-crashes-that-are-not-captured-for-xamarin-android?unresolve=true